# Opengauss+keepalived active/standby switchover, and the active/standby replication relationship is lost

Tags: keepalived, open-gauss

Opengauss + keepalived active/standby switch, and the active/standby replication relationship is lost.

Use opengauss + keepalived to build a high availability environment for simple HA.

Process: After the failure of the primary simulation, the vip also drifts to the standby database. Check the status of the standby database, which has changed from standby to primary. Then, restart the master database, and the master database will preempt back to the vip, which will also drift to the master database. But before, through gs_ The master-slave replication relationship built by ctl build D/gaussdb/data/db1 - M standby is gone, so you need to manually rebuild the relationship.

Question:

1. After the primary database of opengauss is restored, does the previous active/standby replication relationship really disappear? It cannot be self created or automatically modified. Can you only manually re create the relationship?
2. Is there any solution to automatically modify or create a master-slave replication relationship after the failure recovery?

Answer (score 0):

Keepalived.conf configuration file

Use the nopreempt parameter to set it to the non preemptive mode, so that after the master database recovers from the failure, the VIP will not be retrieved from the new master database. However, you need to set the master and backup states to backup.